# How to dismiss modal by tapping screen in ReactNative

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

How to dismiss the modal view by tapping screen in React Naitve, the RN Modal component seems do not provide the api

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use a TouchableWithoutFeedback component within the modal component with an onPress property that dismisses the modal.

```
<Modal visible={booleanThatHandlesModalVisibility}>
  <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => funcToHideModal()}>
    <View>
    ...
    </View>
  </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
</Modal>
```

If you want an area of the modal that doesn't hide the modal on press you can add another TouchableWithoutFeedback without an onPress property to catch the event before the first one like this:

```
<Modal visible={booleanThatHandlesModalVisibility}>
  <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => funcToHideModal()}>
    <View>
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        <View>...</View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    </View>
  </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
</Modal>
```

Comment: I solved my problem with this idea, though I see that ```TouchableOpacity``` doesn't have ```onPressOut```, and I had to use ```TouchableOpacity``` with empty action instead of ```TouchableWithoutFeedback```