# How to swipe a FlatList inside a Touchable in react-native

Tags: react-native

I wanted to ask how can one swipe a horizontal FlatList nested as a first child of a TouchableOpacity? Every time i try to swipe i just activates the TouchableOpacity's onPress.

Happens in both android and ios.

version 0.61.5 of RN

Comment: dose this help you ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33060859/react-native-touchable-is-disabling-scrollview

Comment: Hi, how did you went through this?